# Getting daylight savings time in Power Automate

Tags: datetime, automation, power-automate

I have a flow which runs daily at 1am, setting some parameters for local time 9am to 5pm.

However, when daylight savings time ends the time goes to 8am to 4pm.

I am currently manually editing the times come DST, but thought there might be a way to automate it part of the flow.

AUS DST starts on the first Sunday in October 2am and ends on the first Sunday in April 3pm.

What I am trying to do is create two variables: `StartTimeUTC` and `EndTimeUTC` with one of the 9am to 5pm UTC times:

[image]

Then I would update this variable if DST starts or ends to a new hardcoded +/- hour.

I thought a good way to do this is with a condition, and if the DST time is true then update those two variables with the new HH value, otherwise do nothing. But I'm finding it hard to know what parameters it should be.

My questions are:

- What would I need to add into the conditional so it updates only on DST time parameters?
- Is there a better way to detect DST?

My conditional at the moment (before I got stuck) was:

- Two groups
- AND conditional for the two groups
- Three rows in each group

  - G1 Row 1: `formatDate(utcNow(), 'dd') <= 07      // is it in the first week`
  - G1 Row 2: `formatDate(utcNow(), 'MM') == 04      // is it April`
  - G1 Row 3: `formatDate(utcNow(), 'ddd') == Sun    // is it Sunday`
  - G2 Row 1: `formatDate(utcNow(), 'dd') <= 07      // is it in the first week`
  - G2 Row 2: `formatDate(utcNow(), 'MM') == 10      // is it October`
  - G2 Row 3: `formatDate(utcNow(), 'ddd') == Sun    // is it Sunday`

[image]

But this is wrong because it only would run on the first Sunday in April AND the first Sunday in October, so it would always be false (since the date will never be at two places at once).

If I update it so it is greater than "04" and less than "10" for the months, then it only runs on Sundays between April and October.

At best I can only get it to work if I set it to check if it is greater and "04" and less than "10" so it runs true everyday between April and October. However, if in April the first Sunday (when DST ends) is the 7th of the month, then I would have 6 days of incorrect time in the variable. The same occurs of October.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, from what I can work out, you want to determine if it is or is not daylight savings for your given timezone, is that correct?

Comment: @Skin that is correct but there doesn’t seem to be any in built way to do that

Comment: I think I can help you but you may not like the solution. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other way you might be able to do this is to use the `dateDifference` expression and then evaluate the amount of hours that is resulting.

If you're in Sydney, <kbd>11</kbd> hours would indicate that it's DST and <kbd>10</kbd> would indicate that it's not.

This is a flow that shows the thinking ...

[image: Flow]

##### Variables

Initialize UTC Now
... `utcNow()`

Initialize Sydney Now ... `convertFromUtc(variables('UTC Now'), 'AUS Eastern Standard Time')`

Hours Difference ... `int(first(split(dateDifference(variables('UTC Now'), variables('Sydney Now')), ':')))`

From there, you can set a variable (e.g. `Is DST`) to be true if the value equals 11.

#### Results

##### Is DST (you can see the date is in December)

Initialize UTC Now Expression = `addDays(utcNow(), -150)`

[image: Is UTC]

##### Is NOT DST (you can see the date is is May)

Initialize UTC Now Expression = `utcNow()`

[image: Is Not DST]

Comment: Clever and works!

Answer (score 1):

You may not like this approach but you can go a bit deeper and use the `C# Script Execute` operation in the `Advanced Data Operations` connector.  It makes it very easy and will keep your flow a lot cleaner.

This is where my answer may fall down.  The connector isn't free but it's hell cheap and given it's a 3rd party connector, you will need a premium PA licence.

[image: Flow]

You don't need to specify a variable with your timezone filter but I have just for demo purposes because it's easier to see.

The script is thus ...

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Single(x => x.DisplayName.Contains(parameters.TimeZoneFilter));

var dateTimeUtc= DateTime.UtcNow;
var dateTimeLocal = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTimeUtc, timeZoneInfo);

return timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(dateTimeLocal);
```

... and you an see I've passed in the timezone filter as a parameter.

Here are a couple of results ...

##### Not DST using current date/time (13/05/2023 - 7:30am)

[image: Not DST]

##### Is DST using older date/time (13/01/2023 - 7:30am)

[image: Is DST]

Comment: I actually love that response, and I hope it helps someone who can add on premium actions. I'm unfortunately under the base tier from IT so I have no control over the plugins. It looks clean, but I'd need a solution with the Built-In or Standard options.

Comment: You should ask your IT guys for your own resource group in Azure, that way, you could create a LogicApp and use the connector there and pay for it on a consumption basis. It’ll basically be free. Don’t take no for answer. 